# How to select values from multiselect dropdown which is angular and does not have select class - using selenium webdriver?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, select, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down which has no select class or any id related to it. It uses nya-bs-option and li in the list.

How to do multiselect for this using selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath or css selector instead of class or id.

[check xpath, css selector in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCE23.png)

[xpath]
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

[css selector]
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: <div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 162px;">
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner" style="max-height: 162px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: auto; display: block;">
<!-- nyaBsOption: country in countries -->
  <li nya-bs-option="country in countries" data-id="AX" class="ng-scope nya-bs-option">
         <a tabindex="0" class="ng-binding">
             Aaland Islands
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
         </a>

Comment: This is how the drop down looks..i need to pass a country name as argument and click on that country name if found. It is also multi select - how to perform these actions?